# MongoDb query to get all values of variable in collection with a condition

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I have a collection `depdata` in MongoDb. This contains below json data:

1st document:

```
{
    "Type": "R1",
    "Score": "20"
}
```

2nd document:

```
{
    "Type": "R2",
    "Score": 340"
}
```

I am using python and connected to the database. I have to get the values of the variable `Score` from all the documents in the collection `depdata`. For this I can do below:

```
val = depdata_collection.distinct('Score')
```

and this gives me the values of all the `Score` in the collection as list. But here I want to apply the condition where `Type` should only be `R2`. How can I write query for this and get the values only where `Type` is `R2`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use second argument in the distinct query

```
val = depdata_collection.distinct('Score', { "Type": "R2" })
```